# a verb for saying/understanding something in some terms

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Sometimes we say phenomena in terms of debates in some fields of knowledge.

For example:

> In epistemological terms, the problem is the lack of process
>   reliability.

What to put in the blank in the corresponding question?

> How to ___ the problem in epistemological terms?

It is about talking or understanding the problem in terms of the debates in epistemology. I have "construe" in mind, but I am not sure if it has not ambiguity. "understand" seems a good fit too, again not sure if it is not ambiguous.

Comment: "Comprehend" or "assimilate"?

Comment: I'd expect 'practical' rather than 'epistemological' in your example; if 'process' is being used in a non-industrial (etc) way, this should be pointed out.

Comment: The blank could be any verb, but you haven't really explained what you want that verb to say. *Understand, represent, explain, comprehend* are all reasonable from your question, but they represent diametrically-opposed viewpoints.

Comment: I think ***state*** would work fine there as well.

Answer (score 2):

"*How to **interpret** the problem in epistemological terms?*" would be a good fit:

> **interpret** verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to give or provide the meaning of; explain; explicate; elucidate: to interpret the hidden meaning of a parable.
> 2. to construe or understand in a particular way: to interpret a reply as favorable.
> 3. to bring out the meaning of (a dramatic work, music, etc.) by performance or execution.
> 4. to perform or render (a song, role in a play, etc.) according to one's own understanding or sensitivity: The actor interpreted Lear as
>      a weak, pitiful old man.
>
> *(ommitting other senses)*
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interpret

Another alternative would be ***analyse***:

> **analyze** verb (used with object)
>
> 2. to examine critically, so as to bring out the essential elements or give the essence of: to analyze a poem.
> 3. to examine carefully and in detail so as to identify causes, key factors, possible results, etc.
>
> *(ommitting other senses)*
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/analyse

Answer (score 1):

For epistemology or any other idea-replete domain or type of specialized knowledge, the best verb to describe the action of thoroughly absorbing the notional contents thereof would be, in my opinion, the verb [**to grasp**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grasp), as ideas, if they are to be completely internalized *within* one's noetic system, can only be grasped, meaning both complete logical comprehension and metaphorical holding on to them, in a permanent manner:

> **1.2** Comprehend fully.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use the phrasing "[how to **frame** a problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20to%20frame%20the%20problem%22) (in certain terms)".

Answer (score 0):

The verb ***characterize*** works here (as do its synonyms *depict, portray and present*, perhaps to a lesser extent). Refer to the ODO examples below.

Macmillan:

> **[characterize](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/characterize)**.
>   *VERB [TRANSITIVE]*
>
> **1** to describe someone or something as a particulartype of person or thing
>
> characterize someone/something as something:
>
> The military is usually characterized as being very conservative.

ODO:

> **[characterize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/characterize)**
>
> *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **1** Describe the distinctive nature or features of.
>
> ‘Second, this study suggests that drugs have to be characterized also
>   in terms of the timescale of their effects.’
>
> ‘The text can be characterized in terms of its length and inherent
>   interest.’